# Фильтр по диапазону дат в datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

На форме таблица, которая грузится из БД SQL и 2 datetimepicker. В таблице есть столбец формате data. Нужно по нажатию кнопки отфильтровать по диапазону дат. т.е выбрал 23.08 в первом пикере и 5.09 в другом. по нажатию кнопки должны остаться строки с 23.08 по 05.09. Сколько тем перерыл даже не пойму как сделать фильтр или перезаполнять таблицу. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот попытка сделать но ошибка в том что Dt1.Value.ToString("yyyy / MM / dd") не воспринимает и надо создать переменную уууу и ММ

```
query = "Select* from dbo.Returntable Where Date BETWEEN '{Dt1.Value.ToString("yyyy / MM / dd")}' and '{Dt2.Value.ToString("yyyy / MM / dd")}'";
dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dbAdp);
dbTable = new DataTable();
dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dbTable;
Returndgv.DataSource = bs;
Returndgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте _параметризованные_ запросы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Может, забыли $@ перед строкой: query = $@"Select* from dbo.Returntable Where Date BETWEEN '{Dt1.Value.ToString("yyyy / MM / dd")}' and '{Dt2.Value.ToString("yyyy / MM / dd")}'";

Comment: А почему вы удалили ответ? Он, в принципе правильный. Разве что `AddWithValue` заменить на `Add` с указанием точного типа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, точно. Подозреваю, что Вы хотели это (привожу код для теста):

```
[Test]
public void TestStringVerb()
{
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dt2 = dt1.AddDays(1);
    string s = $@"Select* from dbo.Returntable Where Date BETWEEN '{dt1:yyyy/MM/dd}' and '{dt2:yyyy/MM/dd}'";
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Результат выполения:

```
Select* from dbo.Returntable Where Date BETWEEN '2021.09.03' and '2021.09.04'
```

Оно?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
query = "Select* from dbo.Kassa Where Date BETWEEN @date3 and @date4 ";
        SqlDataAdapter dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
        dbAdp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date3", dt3.Value);
        dbAdp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date4", dt4.Value);
        SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dbAdp);
        dbTable = new DataTable();
        dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dbTable;
        KassaDGV.DataSource = bs;
```